# Will Google Identity Toolkit for iOS support bitcode?

Tags: ios, google-identity-toolkit, bitcode

When building against the CocoaPods version of Identity Toolkit, the following error is encountered:

```
ld: '{path to app}/Pods/GoogleIdentityToolkit/Libraries/libGITkit.a(GITAccount.o)' does not contain bitcode.
You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is this an expected error, now that most Google pods support Bitcode?

Comment: for now you can disable bitcode and continue, hopefully google will fix it soon and provide us an update

Comment: yes, indeed, it does build without bitcode - i know that, but i would prefer not to ship my app without it just because we chose GitKit.

mostly i'm filing this to hear from Google (hopefully they are working on it) and create a central point for us all to complain ;)

Comment: Yes hopefully, soon Google will update us :)